# Connect to Sql Server on liberty using mssql-jdbc

Tags: java, sql-server, websphere-liberty, mssql-jdbc, open-liberty

I'm trying to connect to a Sql Server database from a liberty server.
Doesn't work as I'm getting a 500 from the liberty server and the logs give me this error message: `The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: SQL Server did not return a response.`

My xml:

```
<library id="sqlServerLib2" apiTypeVisibility="spec,ibm-api,api,third-party"
    <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/lib/global" includes="mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar"/>
</library>

<dataSource id="myDataSource" jndiName="jdbc/myDataSource">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="sqlServerLib2"/>
    <properties.microsoft.sqlserver
                        serverName="localhost"
                        portNumber="8080"
                        databaseName="my_db"
                        user="user"
                        password="password"/>
    <connectionManager maxPoolSize="100" minPoolSize="0"/>
</dataSource>
```

I've looked at [IBM's pages](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html). Didn't give much help.

I've also googled the error message but people usually say that I should just update my driver to at least 4.2. I'm using 6.1, so that doesn't really apply.

What am I missing here?
Thanks.

EDIT:
I took a look at [Microsoft's pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix) and found that i was using an incompatible jdbc-api version. I changed this from 4.0 to 4.1.

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
</featureManager>
```

I also defined the dataSource and connection pool classes in my `datasource`.

```
<jdbcDriver libraryRef="sqlserverLib2" 
javax.sql.DataSource="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource"
javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource"/>
```

Now I'm getting a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource`.

I tried using the `mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar`(java 7) instead. Then all of a sudden i worked. What am I doing wrong with the jre8 version of the driver?

Comment: Your server is configured to use encypted connections and your connection is not

Comment: Are you sure your SQL Server is listening on port 8080? That port is usually for (internal) http use, definitely not for SQL Server.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The port and server address is correct. These are just placeholders.

Comment: @sepupic How to i configure my connection to be encrypted? is encrypted false by default?

Comment: <your connection is not encrypted as your connection string does not contain encrypt=true. Please read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-with-ssl-encryption

Comment: @sepupic see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main error was that I used a version of the jdbc-api that was incompatible with the mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar driver. Changing to version 4.1 fixed it.

The classNotFoundException was just a blunder on my part(forgot to update the pom.xml)

Answer (score 0):

In your example code snippet, you have incorrect syntax for specifying the JNDI name of the data source,

```
<dataSource id="myDataSource" jndi="jdbc/myDataSource">
```

This should instead be:

```
<dataSource id="myDataSource" jndiName="jdbc/myDataSource">
```

Comment: Right, edited. Though just a typo as I am unable to copy-paste from my working project(another machine on a closed network).